# Routing Error Adaptive Payments Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, routes

I've come as far as I can and need help with this (please!).  I'm trying to set up payments for items in my peer to peer marketplace.  I think I've set up everything properly, but when I press the pay button I created, it does not redirect to PayPal, instead it seems to just refresh the item page.  I think it is a routing error, but am not entirely positive.

Here's what I've got in my Item model:

```
   class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user 
      belongs_to :category 
      default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

      def recipients
       [
         { email: '<biz email address>', amount: '1.00', primary: false },
         { email: 'item.user.booth.paypal_email', amount: '5.00', primary: true }
       ]
      end
    end
```

In the Items controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
      include ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations
        before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :new, :destroy]
      before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

        def show
            @item = Item.find(params[:id])
        end


      def gateway
        @gateway ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalAdaptivePayment.new \
        login: '<login email>',
        password: '<password>',
        signature: '<signature>',
        appid: 'APP-80W284485P519543T'

        response = gateway.setup_purchase \
        return_url: root_url,
        cancel_url: item_path,
        #ipn_notification_url: <notification URL>,
        receiver_list: recipients

        redirect_to gateway.redirect_url_for(response['payKey'])
      end
end
```

And the link to the button is in views/items/show:

```
<%= link_to "Buy Now with PayPal", @gateway, class: "btn btn-primary col-md-8", id: "paypal-buy-btn"%>
```

I'm also wondering if the error could be because I did not define @gateway in the show action, but when I try to do that I also get errors.

Can anyone help me try to solve this puzzle?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: We've had your code checked by our Ruby guy. He didn't like it or doesn't see the whole picture. Hence, this is just a comment.

In the long run, I would suggest using a working git e.g. https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment seems promising and has some more detailed documentation on chained payments (the links to x.com are a bit outdated)

Comment: That is exactly the git I used and the documentation is also not thorough, especially not for beginners.

Comment: What does `response['payKey']` return? What does `gateway.redirect_url_for(response['payKey'])` return? Also, I think the amounts for the recipients need to be floats, not strings, but I'm not 100% sure (ActiveMerchant may accept both?).

Answer (score 0):

Couple things here in addition to my comment, I'll edit this answer or delete it later if it doesn't actually help. Just needed to answer instead of typing in the tiny comment box.

First thing, your view refreshes because `@gateway` is `nil`, so you're linking to `nil`, which does nothing. You'll need to define a route for your `gateway` method, like so:

```
resources :items do
  post :gateway, on: :member
end
```

Now you will have `gateway_item_path(item)` defined, so you will link to that instead:

```
<%= link_to "Buy Now with PayPal", gateway_item_path(@item), method: :post, ... %>
```

Now your `gateway` method will be hit whenever you click the link. In your gateway method, you'll need to find the `Item`, just as in show:

```
@item = Item.find(params[:id])
```

When you setup the Gateway, you'll need to pass in the item to the cancel url so that it goes back to that specific item, so change that to:

`item_url(@item)`

And change your recipients to `@item.recipients`, since you've defined that method on the model.

Let me know how it goes!